# How do I remove a substring from in between strings using python

Tags: python, regex, string

I've the following string

```
s = 'qwe starting alskdjklas jkld l;ksdl;kas l;;lask \n klasdkl;lasd \n ending askldjla'
```

I want to remove anything that is in between starting ... ending.

the output i want to expect is

```
qwe askldjla
```

Is there a way to do it using python re?

Comment: what does mean *in between starting ... ending* ?

Comment: I just wanted to remove any string or data that is in between the two strings.
I got my answer i was doing some syntax error using flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex

```
import re

s = 'qwe starting alskdjklas jkld l;ksdl;kas l;;lask \n klasdkl;lasd \n ending askldjla'
s = re.sub(r'starting.*ending', '', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(s)
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/IJVb/1.js"></script>
```

Comment: **Real Tahnks** @EyuelDK
You're a Life saver dude Triple thumbsup.

Comment: You should check out my no regex solution. I believe it simpler just because you avoid regex.

Answer (score 1):

Without Regex

```
s = 'qwe starting alskdjklas jkld l;ksdl;kas l;;lask \n klasdkl;lasd \n ending askldjla'
s = s[:s.index('starting')] + s[s.rindex('ending') + 6:]
print(s)
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/IJVb/2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s.index("starting")` which will give you the the index of starting.  In this case it would return `4` as the index of `"starting"`.

Do the same with `"ending"` but offset it by the length of `"ending"`.